# code is still using old IP even though server nslookup showing new IP

Tags: dns

I have migrated a site to a new server. When I check DNS checkers online it seems that the domain has propogated worldwide.

When I try on the server

```
nslookup www.example.com
```

I get the new IP as expected

When I run PHP code to echo out the IP of the domain...

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com'); echo $ip;
```

I get the new IP,

Yet when I use the site part of the php code is used to access a newly created image but it is still using the .htaccess of the site on the old IP. I know this because I have a maintenance redirect which does not exist on the new IP and it keeps trying to do this redirect.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Try to flush dns cache on server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this can be counter-intuitive, but (assuming you're using Chrome) open Developer Tools. `(Click the Hamburger->More Tools->Developer tools)` Then `click the config gear` to the top right and `check "disable cache while devtools is open"`.

`Refresh the page with devtools open` and see if that gets you to the solution. That will force the browser to pull fresh files from the server each time and help you rule the client's side out. The Network section of devtools when you refresh may help as well. I'm thinking it's the browser's cache.

(Unsure if this is the case, but I could imagine Chrome resolving and storing the IP in cache and only resolving again if that IP doesn't have the file, or a similar mechanism, to minimize unnecessary look-ups.)